# iOS SDK UITabBarController only shows one of two UIViewControllers

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, uitabbarcontroller

I am trying to make an iPhone application with two tabs: One for the game, and one for the instructions.

However, when I add the UIViewControllers using

```
[_tabBarController setViewControllers:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:self.viewController, self.viewController2, nil] animated:NO]
```

it only shows the first one.

I have tried simply setting the title property of each of my view controllers then adding them, I have tried doing

```
[_viewController setTabBarItem:[[UITabBarItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"something" image:nil tag:0]]
```

And also tried doing the previous operation in the `initWithNibNamed: bundle:` method. 
However, nothing I do seems to allow me to show more than the one tab on the screen.
Any help is greatly appreciated.
Thanks,
Michael.

Answer (score 0):

Is viewController2 nil and it just didn't load? Make sure you have it properly connected when using IB.

Comment: I am using the programatic way of defining all my elements (including view controllers) because I am blind, and on mac, the IB is inaccessible. I'm pretty sure it's not nil.

Comment: I have no idea what might be the problem then, sorry.